# How to Load pages without going to varous url?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a single page load application ie load different pages ina single page when the user clicks on a link.

say for example I have three links Home, News and Contact, How can I make them all load in a single page without going to 3 different pages.

How can i do it using pure Native Javascript  and jquery without using backbone or angular just pure javascript and No Frames?

Comment: This concept is called single page application. You might want to look at different javascript MVC frameworks, like backbone.js for example

Comment: @Robert First, it's not necessary. Second, he said: "How can i do it using pure Native Javascript and jquery without using backbone or angular just pure javascript and No Frames? "

Comment: @Yair, the question was edited after my comment, see the history. Furthermore, the concept is indeed called SPA, best achieved with some sort of framework

Comment: @Robert Believe me, I know what SPA is and did it using AngularJs.

Comment: hey its much more easier if we use angular.js.
is it fine if i'll give u a angular.js solution??

Answer (score 1):

The jquery load function should be helpful. It loads a html from the url into specific DOM element.

http://api.jquery.com/load/

You can make a single div and give it a property id="main". Then in onclick event for link Contacts you can call $("#main").load('contact.html'); etc.

Answer (score 0):

hey you are asking it in jquery.

i will suggest you a solution in angularjs

I hope it will work for you ...

just copy past and save it as ".html" and see it working...

look at the comments for better understanding.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<!-- you need to import this script for angularjs to work -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Adding the ng-app declaration to initialize AngularJS -->
<div id="main" ng-app>
    <!-- The navigation menu will get the value of the "active" variable as a class.
         The $event.preventDefault() stops the page from jumping when a link is     clicked. -->

<nav class="{{active}}" ng-click="$event.preventDefault()">

    <!-- When a link in the menu is clicked, we set the active variable -->

    <a href="#" class="home" ng-click="active='home'">Home</a>
    <a href="#" class="projects" ng-click="active='projects'">Projects</a>
    <a href="#" class="services" ng-click="active='services'">Services</a>
    <a href="#" class="contact" ng-click="active='contact'">Contact</a>
</nav>

<!-- ng-show will show an element if the value in the quotes is truthful,
     while ng-hide does the opposite. Because the active variable is not set
     initially, this will cause the first paragraph to be visible. -->

<p ng-hide="active">Please click a menu item</p>
<p ng-show="active">You chose <b>{{active}}</b></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can see this is just one page ... but functions as multiple pages...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. Lets take 3 different dives and give 3 different ids to them such as "home", "news", "contact". And now place the contents you want to load them inside those divs.

your html code will look something like below.

```
  <div id="home">
     <h3>Home Page</h3>

    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>

    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
    onec id elit non mi porta ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
 </div>
 <div id="news">
     <h3>News Page</h3>

     <p>Donec id elit non mi porta ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>

    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
 </div>
 <div id="contact">
   <h3>Contact Page</h3>

    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>

    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
 </div>
```

Now in the navigation will look like below

```
<ul>
    <li ><a onClick="showDiv(1);">Home</a></li>
    <li ><a onclick="showDiv(2);">News</a></li>
    <li ><a onclick="showDiv(3);">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
```

After this define the ShowDiv() method in the header section

```
function showDiv(pageid)
  {
    if(pageid== 1)
        {
        $("#home").show();
        $("#contact").hide();
        $("#news").hide();
        }
    if(pageid== 2)
        {
        $("#home").hide();
        $("#contact")
        $("#news").show();
        }
    if(pageid== 3)
        {
        $("#home").hide();
        $("#contact").show();
        $("#news").hide();
        }
  }
```

Here you go, you can load three page contents in a single page ....

Comment: If this help you to do so then plz mark it as answer....

Answer (score -2):

You can use Ajax like this:

```
    $('#home').click(function(){
        $.get('home.html', function(data){
            document.write(data);
            document.close();
        });
    });
```

But it can't work with cross-origin resource, where you should use CORS or iframe.